# Side menu issue, only in screen showing 25% of side menu

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Side menu issue, only in screen showing 25% of side menu

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue logged under APAR IV78634. Please submit a PMR to IBM Support to have this resolved.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

This issue should get resolved with Maximo Anywhere 7.6 in most cases. Look for version upgrade, which should fix this issue.