# Maximo-Anywhere apps top right menu goes out of browser simulator

Tags: maximo-anywhere

This happens in all the Maximo Anywhere apps in version 7.5.2.1 while opened in Chrome browser simulator.
Top right menu goes out of visible screen and not able to see its content.
Works in Safari, which is not an option on Windows. Same issue in Firefox too.

Comment: I just happened to see the similar question  [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523847/side-menu-issue-only-in-screen-showing-25-of-side-menu/34657543#34657543).

Comment: Issue is resolved in the 4Q release of 7.5.2.1  This is a bug in previous release.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known defect logged under APAR IV78634.  Please submit a PMR to IBM Support to have this resolved.